# Stream a terminal application's GUI inside a view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ncurses

I have been experiencing with the ncurses library for a couple of weeks now and I started wondering if there was a way to wrap the terminal app's GUI inside a Cocoa window.

I've been searching around but I can't seem to find anyone who has done it. I would appreciate any help on the matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using classes from iTerm 2 - which is a complete open source terminal app. That should give you a view with the ncurses support you require. iTerm 2 is on [GitHub](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2).

Comment: So there is no native way of doing this?

Comment: Unsure what you mean by "native" - I do not think there is an Apple provided Cocoa class that emulates a VT100 terminal (or similar), which is what you need for ncurses. iTerm 2 is a Cocoa app and provides such functionality, its open source so if its licence is compatible with your app just use the classes from it.